# Change URL for MSM site

Tags: multi-site-manager

I have an MSM site setup but need to change the domain name. I have the new domain name setup and moved the site files to the new domain directory.

I also updated the URLs in the control panel & in the admin.php & index.php files but it does not work. When I visit the new URL, I get the following message: Your system folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

But the path is correct. What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: Actually, the path was incorrect. I fixed it and now get the Site Error: Unable to Load Site Preferences; No Preferences Found message.

Comment: Anyone? No one has ever had to change the domain for an MSM site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Unbeknownst to me, the host was requiring a database user password update. Not sure why it only effected the new site since all other sites were able to communicate with the database.

Once I updated the password, everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

To change the URL in MSM site you need to change in below variables in `index.php`.

```
$assign_to_config['site_name']  = 'domain2_short_name';
$assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'http://domain2.com/admin.php';
$assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://domain2.com';
```

If you need to change domain name then you should change `$assign_to_config['site_url'] = 'http://new_domain2.com'` and `$assign_to_config['cp_url'] = 'http://new_domain2.com/admin.php'` according to your new Domain name.

Comment: Yes, I have done all of that.

Comment: So, working fine?

Comment: No. It does not work.

Comment: Make sure your main website have all the templates of new site. And new site has only js,css etc folders not ADMIN.

Comment: It does. All I did was move the original domain's site files to the new location on the server for the new domain. Then I changed the site url in the control panel and updated the variables in index.php & admin.php. That should be all there is to do but it still does not work.